# Why web API return 404 when deploy to IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS, VS2013
I have implement a ASP.NET web api, when I debug in VS2013, it can open IE, and I can call my web api correctly. http://localhost:42508/api/log/111

I have use "publish" in VS2013, and deploy all files to `D:\api_publish`.

Now, I set up IIS, and under `"Default Web Site"`, I add a application `"serverapi"`. 
Now I set "physical path" to `D:\api_publish\bin` (where serverapi.dll is at). then I use below URL to access API, http://192.168.1.100/serverapi/api/log/111

But it return `404 - File or directory not found.`

**UPDATE**:

After I set "Default Web Site" to another folder path, and set Application "physical path" to `D:\api_publish\`, Now when I access http://192.168.1.100/serverapi/api/log/111, it will return HTTP 500 error.

Comment: What are the settings on the application pool? Have you set it to use .Net 4?

Comment: Your URL looks incorrect.

Comment: Also, the physical path should probably be a level above the bin folder.

Comment: As my "Default Web Site" is already point to D:\api_publish, if I set application serverapi to D:\api_publish, it will conflict. so What should I do?

Comment: Point the default website to somewhere else!

Comment: Or use the default website for your API

Comment: I use defaultApppool, it seems is .Net 4.

Comment: And does this URL work `http://192.168.1.100/api/log/111`?

Comment: Now, I have modify  "Default Web Site"  to another folder, and set application to  D:\api_publish. when I use http://192.168.1.100/api/log/111 or http://192.168.1.100/serverapi/api/log/111, they are now  both return HTTP 500

Comment: Open that URL on the server itself, you should get a better error message but it looks like it's working now.

Comment: on server, it is also return 500, and no any other error message, I do not know how to do further analysis.

Comment: Well that's a different question I'm afraid!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of issues that I can see here.

1. The physical path should be set to `D:\api_publish` and not in the bin folder.
2. Check the application pool is set to use `.NET CLR Version v4`.

As you mentioned in the comments, the default website already points to the same physical folder. You can either:

1. Move the default website to another path.
2. Use the default website instead of the `serverapi` one you created.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `D:\api_publish` as physical path. `Bin` folder can not be used for that.